# Sonar Complaint Java + Either remove this useless object instantiation of class "ResponseEntity" or use it

Tags: java, sonarqube

My team implemented Sonar code coverage for my project and one the method in class complaining about the error 'Either remove this useless object instantiation of class "ResponseEntity" or use it '. If i remove the line it is complaining it will work. But i want to handle that error as well.

Any suggestions how this to be handled will be appreciated

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/identity", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> createIdentity(@RequestBody @NotNull Heartbeat heartbeat) {

    //Validate
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(heartbeat.getHostname())
            || StringUtils.isEmpty(heartbeat.getEnvironment())
            || StringUtils.isEmpty(heartbeat.getProcessSignature())) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    try {
        byte[] encodedValue = identityService.createIdentity(heartbeat.getHostname(), heartbeat.getEnvironment(),
                heartbeat.getProcessSignature());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new String(encodedValue));
    } catch (BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        log.error("Unable to create entity for the request", e);
        new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); // Sonar Complaint
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: Why do you create the instance if you don't use it? Do you mean to return it?

Comment: Yes Andy. Its going to return with the error details. BTW its not my code ...

Comment: No, it's not returning the error details, it's returning `return ResponseEntity.ok().build();`.

Comment: @RamKarlapudi to add to Andy Turner's comment: there is (most likely) a return missing in the "Complaint line"

Comment: Yes i removed the unwanted return message as below and tested and that error is disappeared in Sonar.                    
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are not returning the response that you think you are in Error scenario. You can solve this by correctly returning the INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR response.

Sonar is just pointing out that probable flaw.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/identity", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> createIdentity(@RequestBody @NotNull Heartbeat  heartbeat) {
    //Validate
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(heartbeat.getHostname())
            || StringUtils.isEmpty(heartbeat.getEnvironment())
            || StringUtils.isEmpty(heartbeat.getProcessSignature())) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    try {
        byte[] encodedValue = identityService.createIdentity(heartbeat.getHostname(), heartbeat.getEnvironment(),
            heartbeat.getProcessSignature());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new String(encodedValue));
    } catch (BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        log.error("Unable to create entity for the request", e);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); 
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```